# Ahlfors's proof that the quotient $\frac{\alpha + i \beta}{\gamma + i \delta}$ exists

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-explanation

This is the first proof in Ahlfors's book, and though I can follow and replicate every step, I don't fully understand why his strategy works.

He sets out to prove that the quotient $\frac{\alpha + i \beta}{\gamma + i \delta}$ exists provided that $\gamma + i \delta \neq 0$. The way he does this is to say that if the quotient existed, it equals $x + iy$. He then multiplies through by $\gamma + i \delta$ and solves a system of two linear equations in $x$ and $y$.

My confusion with the proof is: doesn't it assume the conclusion? It assumes that this is in fact a complex number $x + iy$. It seems to me that this approach doesn't quite *prove* that the quotient exists, but it establishes that if it in fact exists, this is the form it has.

He comments that after we know that the quotient exists, we can multiply through by the conjugate for a simpler proof. How exactly do we prove that it exists, though? Every approach I have in mind is "circular," in some sense. Is the only approach to assume it exists, find the correct form (solution to the aforementioned system), and then perform the multiplication to establish that the multiplicative inverse of $\gamma + i \delta$ exists, so I can multiply $\alpha + i \beta$ by $(\gamma + i \delta)^{-1}$?

Comment: Note that a solution exists because the determinant of the linear system is $\gamma^2 +\delta^2 >0$.

Comment: This looks very much like what's being proved is *not* that the quotient exists, but rather that *when* it exists it has a certain/unique form. Complex division *must* have been defined before this, and the definition *must* have included the condition that the denominator be non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key word is *if*, as in, *if* a solution $x+iy$ existed, *then* the numbers $x$ and $y$ would have to satisfy these linear equations. In fact, it is really an if-and-only-if. As in, the quotient $x+iy$ exists *if and only if* there are numbers $x$ and $y$ to satisfy these linear equations. This is not assuming something false, or assuming what you want to prove, as it could certainly be the case that both of these statements are false. "[false] if and only if [false]" is a true statement, after all.

But, having established this equivalence, the author goes on to say that the linear system *does* have a solution, for X reason, and therefore (by the above/established equivalence), the quotient $x+iy$ exists after all. This is a common occurrence in math; *if* X object existed, *then* Y object would also have to exist (and vice versa!). In fact, we can show Y exists, and therefore X exists after all. We just often skip the subtle steps, because we know in advance that both objects exist.

---

Edit: here is another subtlety. We don't assume the quotient exists by saying "suppose the expression $z_1/z_2$ is meaningful" or something like this. Rather, what does it *mean* for a number $z$ to satisfy $z = z_1/z_2$? What it *means* is that $z \cdot z_2 = z_1$. So, to be completely formal, what you are interested to prove is "for every $z_1$ and $z_2 \neq 0$, there exists a number $z$ such that $z \cdot z_2 = z_1$". The number $z$ is unique (you can also prove this) and therefore $z$ can be seen as a function of $z_1$ and $z_2$, which we denote by $z = z_1/z_2$.

Comment: I'm nor sure if I fully understand the distinction between $z_1/z_2$ existing and being meaningful, as those seem to me to be synonymous. I'd interpret, for example, $z = z_1/z_2$ to mean $z = z_1 \cdot z_2^{-1}$, which would necessitate the existence of the multiplicative inverse of $z_2$. Is this not the correct line of thinking?

Comment: @JohnT Ah, but what is $z_2^{-1}$ except "the element $w$ for which $w\cdot z_2 = 1$"? Ultimately, division is *defined in terms of* multiplication, rather than taken as an operation which exists a priori. When I say an expression (lit. a sequence of symbols like "$z_1$", "$/$", and "$z_2$") is "meaningful", what I mean is that we have a way to interpret it - that is, a definition for the expression. If you define $z_1 / z_2 = z_1 \cdot z_2^{-1}$, you still need to define what $z_2^{-1}$ means.